# Code first migrations database error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I used [this](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals&author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m6-ef6&clip=3&mode=live) pluralsight video on MVC code first migrations to keep my default MVC IdentityDb context and create another context for custom tables.  Since then I get an error trying to connect connecting to the database online:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>   .........

It works locally. My connection string are correct and my context classes point to the right connection string name:

```
public class IdentityDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityDb()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static IdentityDb Create()
    {
        return new IdentityDb();
    }
}

public class CustomDb : DbContext
{
    public CustomDb() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    public DbSet<Inquiry> Inquiry { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
}
```

Connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=***.db.1and1.com; initial catalog=***;uid=***;pwd=***"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I've read that the connection string name should be the same as the context class name but since I have two contexts I need a common name (DefaultConnection) which I've specified in the contexts.

It works connecting to my local database but not when its online so I did wonder if this would relate to the migration history table being up to date online and EF 6 trying to update the database but the entries in the migrations table match.

Any help appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

I tried resetting the EF migrations with [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate) guide thinking if the migrations where out of sync with the online DB it could result in EF trying to re-create the database causing this issue.  However the problem still persists!

I have now added these lines to my context constructors respectively:

```
Database.SetInitializer<IdentityDb>(null);

Database.SetInitializer<CustomDb>(null);
```

This has stopped the error but kind of defeated the purpose of EF because I now have to remove it when creating migrations and manually script the changes to the online DB, then put it back in for the site to work online.

Comment: if the case is you have some migrations done on localdb and now you are trying to connect to server db, it will try to apply those mogrations on serverdb. Along with this you should check user permissions and web.config if it is pointing to right direction or not.

Comment: The login was working previously so connection strings are ok, only thing I could think of is the migration history table might not completely match up since I had to script the db to replicate it online, they where having trouble restoring from a .bak file.  Is there a good way to strip out all migrations to take the EF code trying to replicate old migrations out of the equation?

Comment: When you point to the new server, EF is going to try and create that database. This is because the default [initializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) is CreateDatabaseIfNotExists.It is currently crashing because you do not have rights to create databases. When you are running out of VS it is your rights SQL looks at. When you deploy to IIS, you need to attach a user or group to the appPool that has create rights. Migrations come into play either by using the console or doing them programmatically or via SQL scripts..

Comment: Con strings and credentials are all good, have posted an update above. Tearing my hair out over this..